# How to Print/Export the schema builder?

Tags: schema-builder

I wonder if there is the ability to print / export the schema builder?

If so, where can I find? If not, would be a great idea to implement this feature for future releases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Print/export from Schema Builder is not currently possible, but you can [go vote on the idea](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000apxUAAQ) for a future release.

There is, however, [ERD Tool](https://sites.secure.force.com/appexchange/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003KNErEAO), a free app in the AppExchange that might work for you.

Comment: Thanks man, i go vote this ideia! This would be fantastic.

Comment: The ERD Tool does not actually have any "Export" or "Print" buttons. Nor does its documentation suggest their existence.

Answer (score 6):

One of my first jobs was to print out the schema for the org i took over.

The only way I got the schema builder to "print" was to take screenshots and then place them together in MS Pain or Photoshop.

It looked so horrible I ditched it.

There is a tool out there called SchemaSpy that was able to give me printable ER Diagrams: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/05/12/running-the-force-metadata-jdbc-driver-for-schemaspy/

Comment: I'm curious if anyone has any screenshots of this in action;  I hate the idea of going to the trouble of getting the JARs, installing what seems to be an outdated package (Graphwiz) and finding out it was for nothing.  :-P

Answer (score 2):

There is a product called Safyr that extracts metadata from SFDC and among other things, allows tables to be visualized as e-r diagrams, both within the product itself, and in a bunch of data modelling tools like ERwin, ER/Studio and PowerDesigner.  You can also use Visio, as long as its 2010 or earlier (they took the data modelling capability out of Visio from 2013)

Comment: Submitted a contact form to Safyr;  hopefully it's useful and free or inexpensive.....

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to export/print your schema is to use an ERD tool. I recommend you try [AbstraLinx](https://soft-builder.com/abstralinx/), you will be able to export your schema as a PNG or print it directly.

Hope it helps you.

notice: I work for Softbuilder the company that develops this tool.

Comment: Please indicate if you have any commercial relationship with the supplier of this tool as that is required by our community standards.

Comment: Yes Dave, I work for Softbuilder which is the developer of this tool.

Comment: Hi @John.F - please can you include that in your answer. It is perfectly legitimate for a tool to be put forward as a solution by the developer, but that needs to be clear in the answer so it is clear.