# Schema Builder export (OS)

Tags: schema

Is there anyway to export the Schema builder to get an accurate depiction of the data model in a PDF or any format? I've looked online, and I haven't been able to come up with any alternatives because I believe the native Schema Builder in Salesforce does not allow export

I came across this post [How to Print/Export the schema builder?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/610/how-to-print-export-the-schema-builder)

I have installed ERD tool, but I do not believe it has the capability to export either. The SchemaSpy is actually a really cool idea, however the Graphixz tool that they reference no longer makes applications that run on the most recent OS for mac, so I don't believe that will work either. Does anyone have any ideas about how to export it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SchemaSpy with [Graphviz v2.38](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php) installed on Windows 7 Enterprise and I love it!

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm just gonna have to grab a work laptop with Windows on it and run the job, it looks like a huge hassle right now to use macports...I've looked online and I haven't seen anyone with success stories. Looks like us Mac users are just out of luck on this one.