# Is there a tool to view an organisation's schema outside Salesforce?

Tags: relationships, fields, database, schema, object

For example, if I want to have an image with all the tables and relationships in my organisation, I would have to manually look for every object/field/relationship and build it myself in an external tool (like Draw.io).

Is there a tool to do this automatically?

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/610/how-to-print-export-the-schema-builder

Answer (score 2):

Try SoqlXplorer, you can find it here: http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/

Comment: That is really neat. But it doesn't have an option to export the data as image, or to view multiple objects at the same time. You can focus on one object and on another relationship, but that's it. If you have 3 objects chained, then you can't view the 3rd one.

Comment: you can create an image, click right mouse button, but other is correct, no multiply objects option